# Optimization problem in Python when the dimension of input also varies

Tags: python, list, algorithm, optimization, scipy

Consider the problem of minimizing a function `f(x)` where `x` is a list in Python with variable length from 1 to some integer c. The numbers in the list must be integer and in increasing order. So for example, letting `c = 10`, `x` can be

```
x = [1,5,7]
x = [3,5,8,9]
x = [1,8]
```

The gradient is available, indicated by `df(x)`. How can we code this problem using existing Python optimization algorithms?

Comment: I would use a constraint solver such as https://labix.org/python-constraint for that

Comment: I am not aware of algorithms or tools that can take a dynamically sized set of variables. I would use a vector of binary variables to indicate if variable k is in the set to be considered. Of course, depending on f(x) this may make this an MINLP problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any solver in [SciPy optimize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html) as long as you can modify your function `f(x)` to accept a NumPy array of the maximum allowed size (`c`) and using special value (e.g. `0`, `-1`, `np.nan`, `np.inf`) to reduce the number of dimensions.

Comment: Can you please elaborate how one can define such function? This part is very essential.

Comment: @Saj_Eda The question is ill-posed. You should provide details about your `f(x)` before asking how to adapt it. Otherwise, defining a function based on the number of say `-1` it contains it is just a matter of counting and a bunch of `if`s.

Comment: Typically we don't want to do this as this makes the problem highly nonconvex and not differentiable.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen Again, this depends on the actual form of `f(x)`. For example, this could be a simple `sum()` with `0` being the fill number. In any case, OP indicated that `df(x)` is known. So this is not a problem.

Comment: Back to school moment. Any "if" makes the problem non-differentiable (some special case exceptions).

Comment: So even if the whole model is completely linear, we should never do "a bunch of ifs".

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen What makes you think that this is not an exception? I am not sure why you first say that some exception do exists and then suggest to **never** use a bunch of `if`s?

Comment: Come on. Your `if`s are obviously non-smooth. The exceptions I am talking about, keep things smooth (such as a Huber function). So again, **never, never** use if's in the way you suggested, It is thoroughly bad advice.

Comment: Honestly, I am wondering what makes you think that. I do agree that a branching function may have mathematical properties that make it unsuitable for differential optimization. But you cannot know that this is OP case, which actually say to provide the derivative. There is literally no clue as to what `f(x)` might be. For all you know it could be a polynomial representation where the elements of the lists are just the coefficients and the `0` are omitted, which would make the problem infinitely many differentiable without bothering maths that was introduced in the past 100 years...

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen I think you are projecting your own (very valuable) experience into something which is simply not written anywhere here.

Comment: I am not complaining about the f(x) but rather about your advice to introduce functions that involve a bunch of if's. I see this often in client models implemented by less experienced modelers, and it is always something that should raise red flags.  Again, this is just not something we want to use in optimization models.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen I think I was misunderstood then, as I did not suggest to introduce constraints to begin with. I suggested to define `f(x)` to use a different data structure that just a dynamically sized `list`. This process may require one to use the infamous `if`s. But this is just to rewrite the **same** `f(x)` in a way that can work with fixed-size arrays. This should not change the original mathematical properties of `f(x)`.

Comment: IMHO your suggestion to use if statements remains the wrong advice.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen I did not *"suggest to use if statements"*. I did say that one *can* (**not** *should*) do this with branching. My advice was to show how `f(x)` was defined and that without knowing `f(x)`, branching will *eventually* do. I am not aware of a method that is bound to work irrespective of how `f(x)` is defined other than using branching. While you understandably see a *red flag* when *defining* a function using `if` because that is rarely producing a well-behaved function, this is because `f(x)` gets *new* bad properties. My suggestion **does not touch the original `f(x)` prop**.